# Matrix Pointer Syntax

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, matrix

My question is why did they use (`int**`) in the declaration of the `matrix` pointer as a pointer to an array. Is it necessary? What difference does it make?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int **matrix;       // Pointer to matrix
    matrix = (int **) new int *[2]; // Why use (int**) is it necessary?
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[2];
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = j + i;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unnecessary and potentially dangerous.

The type of the new-expression is already `int**`, suitable for assigning to `matrix`. There is no need to convert it to its own type.

One should not use C-style casts even when a conversion is necessary. Doing so will force a conversion even if it makes no sense, which is a very good way to hide errors; for example, if you accidentally `new` the wrong type:

```
matrix = new int[2];           // Friendly compiler error
matrix = (int**) new int[2];   // No diagnostic, likely to cause weird
                               // run-time errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason: they are C programmers

In by the book C, it is customary to cast dynamic memory allocation from malloc.

```
matrix = (int**) malloc(2*sizeof(int*));// C
matrix = (int**) new int*[2]; // local argot
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of matrix is `int**`, in this case the `*` is not just a pointer, but it is a pointer to an array. So `**` means a pointer to an array of pointers to an array. Which is how you get the 2 dimensions that a matrix is.